# Angular Firestore sometimes duplicate entries

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, object, google-cloud-firestore

Something I've noticed when coding in Angular Typescript is when using Firestore I occasionally get double entries.

An example of this would be

HTML

```
<button id="excel" disabled="disabled" class="excel" (click)="exportToExcel($event)">{{button}}</button>
<div *ngFor="let item of classes | async" 
[ngClass]="{check:addItem
(item.data.Device,
item.data.Humidity,
item.data.Index,
item.data.Raw,
item.data.Resistance,
item.data.Temperature,
item.data.VDD,
item.data.VOC,
item.data.Time,
item.id)}">
</div>
```

.TS (Normal code)

```
 json = [];

  addItem
 (
_Device:string,
_Humidity:string,
_Index:string,
_Raw:string,
_Resistance:string,
_Temperature:string,
_VDD:string,
_VOC:string,
_Time:string,
_ID:string,
)
{

let jsonObject = {
  Device: _Device,
  Humidity: _Humidity,
  Index: _Index,
  Raw: _Raw,
  Resistance: _Resistance,
  Temperature:_Temperature,
  VDD:_VDD,
  VOC:_VOC,
  Time:_Time,
  ID:_ID,
};

this.json.push(jsonObject);

}
```

.TS (For loop to prevent dupe entries)

```
json = [];

  addItem
(
_Device:string,
_Humidity:string,
_Index:string,
_Raw:string,
_Resistance:string,
_Temperature:string,
_VDD:string,
_VOC:string,
_Time:string,
_ID:string,
)
{

let jsonObject = {
  Device: _Device,
  Humidity: _Humidity,
  Index: _Index,
  Raw: _Raw,
  Resistance: _Resistance,
  Temperature:_Temperature,
  VDD:_VDD,
  VOC:_VOC,
  Time:_Time,
  ID:_ID,
};
let Bools = false;
for (let i = 0; i < this.json.length; i++)
{
  if (this.json[i].ID == _ID)
  {
    Bools = true;
    break;
  }
}

if (Bools == false)
{
this.json.push(jsonObject);
}
}
```

So my question is, in Angular Firestore why is this returning duplicates of every entry?
I fixed the problem with a simple for loop, but I've noticed sometimes I get duplicate entries or even triple entries in my object `json` . Everything you see in my HTML is my entire HTML as an example.

Comment: Have you checked the database? Maybe the entries are duplicated.

Comment: The data base on Firestore has absolutely no duplicates. Made sure I checked there.